# Checking if vector is normalized

Tags: c#, floating-point

I tried to check if my vector struct is normalized, and I ended up with this code:

```
public bool IsNormalized
{
    get
    {
        double len = Length; // Math.Sqrt ((X * X) + (Y * Y) + (Z * Z)); -- X, Y, Z are in double format

        const double min = 1 - 1e-14;
        const double max = 1 + 1e-14;

        return (len >= min && len <= max);
    }
}
```

Is this solution OK? I read double has 15 digits precision, but 1+1E<sup>-15</sup> give 1, so I changed to E<sup>14</sup>.

Is this all good? I need best accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems ok, depending on how precise you want it to be (some margin of error will always be needed since this *is* floating-point, but how much will depend on your needs)

Alternatively, you could check `Math.Abs(1 - len) < 1e-14`, but I suspect the same precision problems will remain.

I was somewhat surprised that `1 + 1e-15` equals 1, though, because doubles have 52 bits of precision, which should be more than enough to store a difference of 15 digits (`-log2(1/10^15)` gives me around `49.8`, which is less than 52 bits).

So I double checked and 1 - 1.0e-15 does **not** give me 1.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1 - 1.0e-15); //Does NOT print 1
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Same thing for 1 + 1.0e-15 (though this one is trickier)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1 + 1.0e-15); //Prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(1 + 1.0e-15 == 1); //...but this prints False
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I suspect Console.WriteLine is only printing a limited number of digits: less than the ones double can represent.

As a final note, Sqrt(1) == 1, so instead of using the Length you could use the SquaredLength and save a (potentially expensive) `Sqrt` operation.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I looked in debugger now, and, like you said, it's not equal 1. So I will stick to 1E-15. Also thanks for the SquaredLength tip. I did not understand why it was exposed in some Vector 3D implementations, but now I know it's very useful in my IsNormalized property.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that my Sqrt tip is only needed if you're being bottlenecked. For most "casual" uses, your function works perfectly (and is perhaps more readable)

Comment: "I suspect Console.WriteLine is only printing a limited number of digits: less than the ones double can represent."  -  This should be a well known fact - console is intended to interface with human operators, not examine the miniature of double.  If you want more information, look into the double ToString options.